# Preventing race condition in parent relation in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, locking, race-condition

I have the following models:

```
class Lyric < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :song
  after_create :add_to_song
end

class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many   :lyrics
end
```

The idea is that a user can add any number of lyrics for a song. If a lyric is entered for a new song that doesn't yet exist for that user, a new song is created for that user. This is achieved by calling the after_create method 'add_to_song' which checks whether the user has any lyrics from that song:

```
def add_to_song

  sl = self.song_line

  # Check for adjacent songs
  prior_song = Song.where(:user_id => self.user.id, 
                          :title=> sl.title, 
                          :artist => sl.artist, 
                          :last_line => sl.linenum-1).first

  next_song  = Song.where(:user_id => self.user.id, 
                          :title=> sl.title, 
                          :artist => sl.artist, 
                          :frst_line => sl.linenum+1).first

  # Case 1 - No existing song
  if !prior_song && !next_song
    song = Song.create!(:user_id => self.user.id, 
                        :length => 1, 
                        :title=> sl.title, 
                        :artist => sl.artist, 
                        :frst_line => sl.linenum, 
                        :last_line => sl.linenum )
    self.update_attribute( :song_id, song.id )

  # Case 2 - Lyric is between two songs -> merge songs
  elsif prior_song && next_song
    prior_song.absorb( next_song, self )

  # Case 3 - Lyric is new first lyric of existing song
  elsif next_song
    next_song.expand( self )

  # Case 4 - Lyric is new last lyric of existing song
  else
    prior_song.expand( self )
  end

end
```

The add_to_song method also combines two 'songs' into one if the linking Lyric is added by a user. In other words, if a user has the 1st and 3rd line of a song they are regarded as two different songs until she adds the 2nd line of that same song.

### The Problem

When a user adds multiple lyrics from the same song simultaneously (by selecting a number of them from search results), a race condition occasionally occurs in MySQL and two song models are instantiated for the same song, even though the lyrics are adjacent to each other and should be combined into a single 'Song'. (The unfortunate result of this is that the lyrics are presented in the correct order.)

I have read endless posts on optimistic vs pessimistic locking etc. and have tried various options but can't seem to get rid of the problem. It seems to be quite an overkill to lock the entire Song table every time a user creates a Lyric.

Is that the only way to prevent this from happening? (It appears to be a huge hit to performance).
Do I have something fundamentally wrong in my schema? I would imagine that this is a common problem in many projects but it doesn't seem to come up too frequently as far as I can tell. It would appear that any time a parent association is instantiated in an after_create method, there is a chance of a race condition if the creation of the parent model (in this case, Song) is dependent on the existence of another child (in this case, Lyric).

Comment: When a user selects a whole bunch of lyrics from a search, and adds them as a single song - doesn't your controller know that it's a single song being created (or updated) with a set of lyrics? Perhaps it'd be better to create the song there, rather than in the lyric-after-create hook?

Comment: Can you add the add_to_song method? Do you have a condition in that method to check if a song already exists?

Comment: I've added the add_to_song method.

Comment: It seemed cleaner to separate the add_to_song method out as an after_create hook.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to lock the table, there is an ugly way to prevent that from happening: mutexes.

Something like this:

```
File.open(MUTEX_FILE_PATH, "w") unless File.exists?(MUTEX_FILE_PATH)
mutex = File.new(MUTEX_FILE_PATH,"r+")
begin
  mutex.flock(File::LOCK_EX)

   ...code...

ensure
  mutex.flock(File::LOCK_UN)
end
```

Would work without blocking the entire table. You can do even better for performance and create a mutex using the user ID, this way the block will work for each user, not for anyone.

I didn't really get the check next song and check previous song thing, but if you do user has_many lyrics through songs don't works better than your current user has_many songs through lyrics?